# Prevent view to be in front during animation

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

I have a button that shows or hides a view. When button get pressed the view is added to layout and a translate animation begins. Second button press will remove the view from the layout.
I user `addView(view, 0)` to make sure the view is behind all other views. It works generally fine.

The problem occurs when the view is shown and I  press the button twice very fast (sort of double click). In that case the view jumps to front during the animation.

How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just disable( `setEnabled(false)` ) the button and enable it in `AnimationListener.onAniationEnd()`.

**UPD**: ok, that's the code, which illustrates my idea:

```
    final Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myButton);
    View view = (View) findViewById(R.id.myView);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            btn.setEnabled(false);
            // animation here
            addView(view, 0);
        }
    });

    // somewhere else
    final Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myButton);
    btn.setEnabled(true);
    removeView(view);
```

Comment: I don't use animation when i hide the view. I just remove it using removeView(view).

Comment: hmmm... than i could not click on it

Comment: because the button would be disabled. I can't enable the button before i add the view.

Comment: why you can't? `View view = findViewById(...); view.setEnabled(true); addView(view);`

Comment: Oh. you are talking about enabling the view or the button?